# How could we get more people to come to the site and post?

Tags: discussion

The Retrocomputing Stack Exchange is very inactive sadly. How can we make more people join this site? Maybe we could post on different social medias and even on some other retro-computing forums.

Comment: Beat me to it! Here's [a recipe to promote our site](//blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/), and community bloggers can backlink to some questions from the blog.